# Representations of knot groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, manifolds, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Recently, I was studying the knot group and I want to learn some more material about it (e.g. its representations).

"Knots" by Burde and Zieschang discusses some material but it is not entirely covered. Also, Rolfsen talks about the fundamental group and Wirtinger presentation but not about the representations in the symmetric group or the dihedral group.

So, what is a good reference for the knot group, its subgroups and its representations (and related topics to the knot groups)?

Comment: Did you check the new edition of Burde and Zieschang, together with Heusner?

Comment: @studiosus I will check those as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can start by reading [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1991-326-02/S0002-9947-1991-1008696-X/S0002-9947-1991-1008696-X.pdf) by Eric Klassen. If you want to read about more recent topics, just take a look at Hans Boden's 
[homepage](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~boden/preprints/index.html): Every other paper will be about representations of knot groups. Or you can dive into [this paper](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~stfriedl/papers/3-manifold-groups-v3.pdf) by Aschenbrenner, Friedl and Wilton. (Warning: It is 149 pages long!) All in all, the literature on this subject is just enormous.